# REACT-ROUTER—Render output in parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this setup in my `main.js`

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={Window}>
    <IndexRoute component={Users} />
    <Route path="users" component={Users}>
      <Redirect from="add" to="edit" />
      <Route path="edit(/:id)" component={UserEdit} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="groups" component={Groups} />
    <Route path="permissions" component={Permissions} />
    <Route path="*" component={Error} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

If the url changs to `users/add` or `users/edit` the `UserEdit` component is available as child of the `Users` Component, so this code `Users.js`

```
render() {
  return (
    …
    {this.props.children}
  );
}
```

Gives me the form right away. But I would like to have to appear the rendered result as child of the `Window` Component, which is the parent component of `Users` in this case.

How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 1):

Hey I tried to recreate your example to check whether you need to add the parent path to render the child component inside the parent component. Here is the code. To recreate this just create a folder in react-router examples and add an index.html and copy this code in app.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { browserHistory, Router, Route, Link,IndexRoute,Redirect } from 'react-router'

import withExampleBasename from '../withExampleBasename';

const Window = (props)=> {
  return (<div>
    Window
    {props.children}
  </div>);
};
const Users = (props)=> {
  return (<div>
    Users
    {props.children}
  </div>);
};

const UserEdit = (props)=> {
  return (<div>
    UserEdit
    {props.children}
  </div>);
};

const Groups = (props)=> {
  return (<div>
    Users
    {props.children}
  </div>);
};

const Permissions = (props)=> {
  return (<div>
    Permissions
    {props.children}
  </div>);
};

const Error = (props)=> {
  return (<div>
    Error
    {props.children}
  </div>);
};

render( (
  <Router history={withExampleBasename(browserHistory, __dirname)}>
    <Route path="/" component={Window}>
      <IndexRoute component={Users}/>
      <Route path="users" component={Users}>
        <Redirect from="add" to="edit"/>
        <Route path="edit(/:id)" component={UserEdit}/>
      </Route>
      <Route path="groups" component={Groups}/>
      <Route path="permissions" component={Permissions}/>
      <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>

), document.getElementById( 'example' ) )
```

Now the Router settings are same as you mentioned in your question. 
And I got everything right, I mean UserEdit was always rendered as child of user which intern is rendered as a child of Window.
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can move the `users/edit` route and change `edit(/:id)` to `users/edit(/:id)`:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={Window}>
    <IndexRoute component={Users} />
    <Route path="users/edit(/:id)" component={UserEdit} />
    <Route path="users" component={Users}>
      <Redirect from="add" to="users/edit" />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Comment: I think that will do the trick, but than I have to retype the `users/` part all the time… I am asking myself if there is a more elegant way, without all this repition…

Comment: Not to my knowledge, would love to be wrong! I had this same problem but do it this way often. All my routes are just flat, I don't use the nesting feature at all for this same reason.

Comment: I think you are wrong https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/RouteConfiguration.md

Comment: @Anup can you clarify what you mean? are you referring to 'Decoupling the UI from the URL'?

Comment: @Conan I was trying to refer to the example in the link they have put
inbox/messages/:id as messages/:id but and now I was trying to build react router to check. But I dont think so you need to write the whole path every time to make child render inside parent. It just give no meaning to child route and parent route

Comment: @Conan can u check my answer if I am geting something wrong

Comment: @Anup your answer is exactly what  philipp doesn't want, he wants to to render only userEdit component not user component when it is in edit mode so the only way is as suggested by Lance or other way around is using common component for user edit and users then based on route calling the required component in commo components render method

Comment: @abhirathore2006 if that what he wants he can take out the route of user/edit out of the users route and put it as child of window and make the route users/edit. I don't think he wants that though

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem using an absolute path to the child pages in the routing:
/users_add instead of users/add
/users_edit instead of users/edit

Sorry, but I didn't find a better solution.